# Parse.com PHP setting ACL to a role returns error

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse.com PHP SDK to develop web application. I am trying to set ACL to a role and I am getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getObjectId() on a non-object in XXXXXXXX/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseACL.php on line 433

this is my code.

```
$userid = $user->getObjectId();
$roleACL = new ParseACL();
$roleACL->setReadAccess($userid, true);
$roleACL->setWriteAccess($userid, true);
$role = ParseRole::createRole($rolename, $roleACL);
$role->save();
$role->getUsers()->add($user);
$roleACL->setRoleReadAccess("SomeRole", true);
$roleACL->setRoleWriteAccess("SomeRole", true);
$role->save();
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.